# Azure Search Features - bury, elevate, blacklist

Tags: search-engine, azure-cognitive-search

Does Azure search provide below features?

1. Bury Scenario with negative boost. I was going through page:  [Scoring profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index). It says, to bury a document, factor of 0-1 can be given. But this might not always be correct, what if document_1 gets a score of 5 and and document_2 score of 2 and the boost factor we give as 0.5, even than the score of document_1 would be greater. So, Do Azure search provides negative boost?
   Let's say I want to give negative boost to a specific brand name for my products, for any search.
2. Does Azure search provides features like elevate IDs/Exclude Ids features like in solr, for elevating or blacklisting products?
   [Solr Elevate/Blacklist feature](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-query-elevation-component.html#TheQueryElevationComponent-TheelevateIdsandexcludeIdsParameters)
3. Does Azure Search provides minimum match feature of edismax parser in solr? Minimum number of keywords to match from query, for a document to appear on result.
   [Solr Minimum Match](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm_MinimumShouldMatch_Parameter)
4. If I make any change in Scoring profile, does that mean index rebuild is required to use scoring profile? As I see its defined with schema.

Answer (score 0):

@Bikas, to your questions

1. This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916307/negative-boost-in-azure-search-profiles) discusses the idea of leveraging negative boost
2. For this elevation, I wonder if [tag boosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index#bkmk_indexref) would work for you where you would tag specific documents that could be elevated as needed?
3. There is a good discussion about [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602738/azuresearch-dismax-query-parser-capabilities).  But no, Azure Search does not support dismax or edismax.
4. If you modify a scoring profile, it will be instantly leveraged by the queries and not index rebuild is required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, point 1 is not quite clear to me. What does he mean by, "negative values". Let's say I want to bury a product with specific "brand name" for any search keyword. What is he suggesting here? can you elaborate

Comment: On the third point, agree most features are supported via other means. But, still do not think "minimum match" feature can be done.